# android listview items vertically stretched

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview

I'm using a view in a listview which embeds a layout with an image background for its rows. The image, and thus rows appear to be vertically stretched where. I use the same layout elsewhere in the app and it appears to be the right size there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_conference_team"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/team_1_logo"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tm_van" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/team_2_logo"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tm_det"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/conference_logo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/team_2_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/east" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team_1_name"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/team_1_logo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/team_van"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp" android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team_2_name"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/team_2_logo"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/team_det"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp" android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/series_info_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_conference_team_series_info"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_below="@id/team_1_name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/series_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/series_info"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/series_info_bg" android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/next_game_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/team_1_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:text="@string/game_time" android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
    android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="11dp" android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_below="@id/series_info_bg" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout which embeds it is the one below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/listview_item_manual" >

  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/header"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/header_blue"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingBottom="8dip"
  android:paddingLeft="10dip"
  android:paddingRight="10dip"
  android:paddingTop="8dip" >
  </LinearLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
  android:background="@android:color/black"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The listView adapter is a custom cursor adapter. I dont do anything special, just inflate the rows from the first layout:

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_series, null);
}
```